# How can i check if a data exist in a firestore database with dart+flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I should check if an username exist in a firestore database, here the database disposition:
[image: Here]

i should so check if userEmail exist on registration (so i say to the user that e cant use that email)
and so even userName, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the login process , u can also get UserID of an User . You can use that UserID to name your documents and then you can check if the document named "UserID" exists or not.

```
    var UserData = await firestore.collection('Users').doc(UserID).get();

    if(UserData.exists != null){
    //Here The User's UserID already existed in Firestore , Perform What You want!!
     }

       else{
    //Here The User's UserID doesn't yet exists in Firestore , Perform What You want!!
       }
```

Comment: sorry, seen this now, thx <3